# Internal sources from proxy not being redirected in Apache

Tags: reverse-proxy, apache2

I set up a proxy like this:

ProxyPass /frontail http://192.168.0.66:9001
ProxyPassReverse /frontail http://192.168.0.66:9001

When I call 192.168.0.66/frontail, it correctly redirects to 192.168.0.66:9001.
However, when rendering that page, it tries to fetch additional resources, but they're not being found, because the server is looking for 192.168.0.66/* instead of 192.168.0.66/frontail/*

How can I adapt all relative sources to keep the proxy path?

Comment: you will have to adapt every single path or just use what I would call "symmetric path reverse proxying" just using  `ProxyPass / http://example.com/` to proxy every request to the backend as it arrives, or make the backend work with the same subdirectory. Otherwise you are in for a lot of pain, trying to addapt everything through ProxyPassReverse directives and/or mod_proxy_html ones. But briefly it rarely you will ever make that work out alright.